# I would a function that incorporates the predict(), table() and then round() code into the function

Tags: predict

The first part of the code below (until the code that reds: Access each model using index), provides the background code so you know what predictions I am using. I am trying to generate a function that incorporates the predict(), table() and round() parts into the function. The code I am using for the predict and table etc can be found at the bottom

```
# Set the seeds for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Define the sampling methods and models
sampling_methods <- c("none", "boot", "LGOCV", "cv", "repeatedcv")
models <- c("LogitBoost", "gbm", "rf")

# Function to fit the caret model
Sth_AM_Proportion_fit_caret_model <- function(sampling_method, model) {
  # Set the seed for the model
  set.seed(sample(1:100, 1))
  
  # Create the caret model control
  ctrl <- trainControl(method = sampling_method)
  
  # Fit the caret model
  Sth_AM_Proportion_fit <- train(Lethal ~ .,
                                 Sth_AM_SP_Train_Final, method = model, trControl = ctrl)
  
  # Return the fitted model
  return(Sth_AM_Proportion_fit)
}

# Iterate over sampling methods and models using purrr
Sth_AM_Proportion_results <- crossing(sampling_method = sampling_methods, model = models) %>%
  mutate(model_fit = map2(sampling_method, model, Sth_AM_Proportion_fit_caret_model))

# Print the results
print(Sth_AM_Proportion_results$model_fit)

# Save the outputs for each model
for (i in seq_along(Sth_AM_Proportion_results)) {
  sampling_method <- sampling_methods[i]
  model <- models[i]
  output <- Sth_AM_Proportion_results[[i]]
  
  # Save the output using appropriate naming convention
  saveRDS(output, paste0(sampling_method, "_", model, "Sth_AM_Proportion_output.rds"))
  
}

# Access each model using index

# Boot GBM #
Sth_AM_Proportion_boot_gbm <- Sth_AM_Proportion_results$model_fit[[1]]

Sth_AM_Proportion_boot_gbm_pred <- predict(Sth_AM_Proportion_boot_gbm, 
                                           Sth_AM_SP_Test,
                                           type = "raw")

Sth_AM_Proportion_boot_gbm_tab <- table(Actual = Sth_AM_SP_Test$Lethal, 
                                        Predicted = Sth_AM_Proportion_boot_gbm_pred)

Sth_AM_Proportion_boot_gbm_CEM <- round(compute.eval.metrics(Sth_AM_Proportion_boot_gbm_tab) * 100, 2) 
Sth_AM_Proportion_boot_gbm_CEM
```